# Is fixed point property a topological property?

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Is fixed point property a topological property?

I already came up with some examples, and think the answer may be yes. But I don't know theoretical proof to get that.

Comment: How do you define "fixed point property"?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin A topological space X has fixed point property iff every continuous function f : X→X has a fixed point.

Comment: Then the answer is in Wikipedia [Fixed-point property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_property). No need to ask on math.exchange

Comment: @J.-E.Pin actually I'm seeking about a serious theoretical proof behind the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ has fixed-point property and $\phi: X\to Y$ be a homeomorphism. If $f:Y\to Y$ is a continuous function, then $\phi^{-1}\circ f \circ \phi : X\to X$ is also continuous so it has a fixed point, say it $x$. You can easily check that $\phi(x)$ is a fixed point of $f$.